# chartjs tooltip label is adding quotes at improper position while showing

Tags: chart.js

I have created a group bar chart using chartJs.
While showing tooltip on bar, i want to show some part of tooltip string in double quotes ("").
I applied below code:

```
            tooltips: {
                displayColors: false,
                mode: 'label',
                callbacks: {
                    title: function() {},
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var tooltipLabel1 = 'Series '+ '"'+data['datasets'][0]['label']+'" '+
                            'Point ' + '"'+tooltipItem.label.split(" ")[1] + " " + tooltipItem.label.split(" ")[0]+'"';
                        var tooltipLabel2 = 'Value: ' + tooltipItem.value;
                        console.log([tooltipLabel1, tooltipLabel2]); // screenshot attached for this output
                        return [tooltipLabel1, tooltipLabel3];
                    }
                }
            },
```

It working fine but it is showing one of double quote at start and end double quote is removing.
Attached screenshot for this, what exactly it is showing on mouse-hover as well as in screenshot of console.

As well as, when I write console for this, because of json string, it add output in ""
What I can do? really clueless now.
[image: console output]

[image: Tooltip text on mouse-hover]

Comment: Can you provide a working example because it seems to work what you have: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/t42m0ard/9/

Comment: Yes, no major code apart from yours in jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/t42m0ard/9 . Even working in jsfiddle when am pasting of tooltip code. Really clueless!